# How to change the audio sample rate in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, configuration, sample-rate

The default audio sample rate is 48000. Is it possible to change it to other values like 44100?
I log the value of `AudioSettings.outputSampleRate` and it shows 48000. But it doesn't seem possible to change that value.

Comment: If you don't need to do it at runtime can't you just change it in the Inspector?

Comment: Do you mean the inspector for individual audio clip? I want to change the sample rate globally.

Comment: Yeah, I meant per Clip.  Globally? Not sure.